# Filter request with http:// in Nginx

Tags: nginx, configuration

Is there a way to filter request that look like "GET http://example.com" but not filter one that look like "GET /index.html"? In other words what is the Nginx variable that can be used in the "If" clause?

The reason for asking this is that I see in my web site log multiple requests that look like:
"GET http://somesite.com/proxyheader" from users that search for free proxy servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me in 0.8.41:

```
if ($request ~* "^[^ ]+[ ]+[^:]+://" ) { return 400; }
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: yes, but what's the context? does it go within `server {}`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the variables in the nginx config?

Link: [link text](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#Variables)

Can you show us an excerpt of your log files? Is the http://somesite... a parameter (http://example.com/http://seomsite...)?

Regards,
Ben.

Comment: Yes I checked them, but still could not get the one that can be used to differentiate between two types of request. The log lines look like this "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [27/Oct/2010:08:57:41 +0000] "GET http://www.example.com/proxyheader.php HTTP/1.1" 200 556 "-"

Comment: In this case apply a regex to your $request variable. Set an appropriate return code (e.g. 403) and check your logs again.

Good luck!